# Optimizing this SELECT query with Julian date column

Tags: oracle, plsql

This query below takes a long time 1693 seconds to be exact.

```
SELECT MAX(cov_julian(t.tatime)) 
  FROM Table1 t,Table2 a,Table3 c
 WHERE  (t.PERSONID = a.EMPID or t.PERSONID2 = c.Col5) 
   AND cov_julian(tatime) <=sysdate
```

`cov_julian` is an user defined function that converts julian date to date.

how do I optimize this query? please help.

Comment: What is the query plan?  How many rows in each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `SELECT` clause, the only column you really care about here is `tatime`.

If `tatime` is a column on `Table1`, then I would check for existence in, and not join to, `Table2` or `Table3`.

Combined with Ollie's suggestion, the query becomes

```
SELECT MAX(cov_julian(t.tatime)) 
FROM   table1   t
WHERE  t.tatime <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'J'))
AND   (EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   table2        a
               WHERE  a.empid = t.personid)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   table3        c
               WHERE  c.col5  = t.personid2))
;
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is an index on `tatime` then convert the sysdate to julian and directly compare to `tatime`.

e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(cov_julian(t.tatime)) 
  FROM Table1 t,Table2 a,Table3 c
 WHERE (t.PERSONID = a.EMPID or t.PERSONID2 = c.Col5) 
   AND tatime <= to_number(to_char(sysdate,'J'));
```

If not and you have to issue this query, create a function-based index on `cov_julian(tatime)`.

Comment: If I use the second option I have to convert the cov_julian function to a deterministic function?

Comment: I tried to convert the sysdate to julian using to_number(to_char(sysdate,'J')) but the cost just shot up. I will try indexing the cov_julian(tatime) function.

Comment: @Ram, I'm surprised the cost increased a lot as the sysdate only needs to be converted once for the query. Is this query part of a cursor or something where the sysdate value could be passed in as a bind variable?

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the number of times the UDF is called.  This assumes that tatime values can be compared by MAX successfully:

```
SELECT COV_JULIAN(MAX_TIME) FROM
  (SELECT MAX(t.tatime) AS MAX_TIME 
     FROM Table1 t,
          Table2 a,
          Table3 c 
     WHERE (t.PERSONID = a.EMPID or t.PERSONID2 = c.Col5)  
           AND tatime <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'J'))) x
```

PL/SQL functions called from an SQL statement are Bad News, and you want to do absolutely everything possible to minimize the number of times they're called.  More recent version (10g+) are supposed to be "better" than older versions, but still - you *really* want to do this as little as possible.

Share and enjoy.