# Alter a timestamp column in an oracle table with default value as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: oracle, timestamp, default, alter-table

Can we assign a default value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in oracle as we do in mysql as shown below ?

Sample query in mysql:

ALTER TABLE . MODIFY COLUMN  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

Answer (score 1):

No - in Oracle neither year, month, or day can be set to zero. I suggest using NULL instead.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=238ebffafed6135556bb4f7e6aeb245f)

### EDIT

Of course, having now gone back through [one of my old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431804/oracle-11-1-bug-converting-julian-day-number-to-date-or-timestamp) and crawled down a wormhole or two I see that you *can* get a year of zero to be accepted - but it still appears that month and day cannot be zero. To get the year of zero in you have to use an ANSI date literal - e.g. `DATE '0000-01-01'` is considered acceptable. I don't know if the various date routines and date calculations will like this - for example, `TO_CHAR(DATE '0000-01-01', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` produces a result of '00-000-0000', which is certainly not what I'd expect, but perhaps it's good enough for your purposes. Note that you can't go the other way with this - `TO_DATE('00-000-0000', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` produces the expected `ORA-01847 - day of month must be between 1 and last day of month` error.

Does anybody really know what time it is..? :-)

Comment: The year can be zero. Range for year is between -4713 and +9999.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: take a look at the dbfiddle link. The error message for attempting to use 0 as a year is "
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0" - so zero isn't allowed for the year. Same message from both 11.2 and 18c so I think this is pretty consistent across versions. I found some odd issues with dates in Oracle 11.1 - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431804/oracle-11-1-bug-converting-julian-day-number-to-date-or-timestamp) - so you *may* be able to force zero in for the year, but at least `TO_DATE` doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: of course, if you *really* want a year of zero just use `SELECT DATE '0000-01-01' FROM DUAL`. So year zero doesn't exist, but there it is. Put another way - time is a problem. :-}

Comment: Yes, strange. `TIMESTAMP '0000-01-01 00:00:00'`works fine, however `DATE '0000-01-01'`returns `0001-01-01` Anyway, using `NULL` would be the proper solution.

Comment: When I run `SELECT DATE '0000-01-01' FROM DUAL` in PL/SQL Developer I get `00-HH:MM:SS-0000`, which is kinda freaky - apparently an odd interaction between the "impossible" date and PL/SQL Developer's handling of my custom date and time formatting. :-) If I run that same SELECT in SQL\*Plus I get `0000-01-01`. And if I run `SELECT TIMESTAMP '0000-01-01 00:00:00.00' FROM DUAL` in SQL\*Plus I get `01-JAN-00 12.00.00.000000000 AM`. All this under 11.2.